# Differential Equation: Can I further simplify it

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

This is a homework problem from course **Differential Equation**,
which requires me to have **Calculus 2** before taking it.

> $\frac{dy}{dt} = \cfrac{1}{2y+1}$

Here's my solution:

> $$ \int (2y+1) \; \mathrm{d}y = \int (1) \; \mathrm{d}t$$
>   $$ y \cdot (y+1) = t + C$$
>   $$ y + 1 = \frac {t + C}{y} $$
>   $$ y = \frac{t+C}{y} - \frac{y}{y} $$
>   $$ y^2 = t+C-y $$
>   $$ y^2 + y = t + C$$

My Professor said I can stop here and give this as answer.

But I am interested that, is it possible for me to simplify it even further?

If so, with what method?

Comment: You can treat this as a quadratic function in $y$ and solve $y$ in terms of $t$. If you were given some initial conditions, then that would help in determining the branch of the solution you can use.

Comment: This is a general solution without intital condidtion like y(0) = 2.  Are you saying I can solve like $$y^2 + y -C = t$$ ?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can solve as $y^2+y-(C+t)=0$ to get $y=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4(C+t)}}{2}$.

Comment: Huh... that's interesting!  Thanks! :)